# TweetSharp ‘GetRequestToken’ return no token on Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm trying to share picture to twitter in my app with TweetSharp, the code is as follow:

```
TwitterService TwitterApi = new TwitterService("My_consumerKey", "My_consumerKey_Secret");
TwitterApi.GetRequestToken(twitterProcessRequestToken);

private void twitterProcessRequestToken(OAuthRequestToken token, TwitterResponse response)
{
    //...
}
```

but when twitterProcessRequestToken was invoked, the `token` is null and `response.StatusCode` is 'Not Found'.

Because I'm in China now and the government has forbidden accessing to *Twitter.com* with GFW, I have to set up a proxy to access the *Twitter.com*. I don't know if the proxy lead to this problem. But I could access Twitter with IE integrated in WP7.

So how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. It is because I use a proxy server to across the GFW and the proxy server will resist the Authentication Request